# jquery sum specific table rows

Tags: jquery

i have a table with som input fields and i want to sum specific rows. In one column i have more than one total, when is one total in column it works but when is more than one not work. Help please, here is the code: 
    http://jsfiddle.net/cesKr/2/

```
        $(document).keyup(function(){
        var getSum = function (colNumber) {
                var sum = 0;
                var selector = '.col' + colNumber;

                $('#sum_table').find(selector).each(function (index, element) {
                   if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0){
                       sum += parseInt($(element).val());
                   }
                });  

                return sum;        
            };

            $('#sum_table').find('.total').each(function (index, element) {
                $(this).val(getSum(index + 1)); 


            });
        });

<table id="sum_table" width="300" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>Apple</td>
    <td>Orange</td>
    <td>Watermelon</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" class="total" name="one" value=""/></td>

    <td ><input class="col2" type="text" name="one" value="2"/></td>
    <td ><input  class="col3" type="text" name="one" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><input class="col1" type="text" name="two" value="1"/></td>
    <td ><input type="text" class="total" name="one" value=""/></td>

    <td ><input class="total" type="text" name="one" value=""/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td ><input class="col1" type="text" name="tree" value="1"/></td>
    <td ><input class="col2" type="text" name="one" value="1"/></td>
    <td ><input class="col3" type="text" name="one" value="1"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td ><input class="col1" type="text" name="one" value="1"/></td>
     <td ><input class="col2" type="text" name="one" value="1"/></td>
    <td ><input type="text" class="total" name="one" value=""/></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: I'm confused why you have .total fields randomly through the table.  I'm unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: For example in first column i have 21 rows. First 4 i must sum it in row 5, next 3 i must sum it in row 9 etc.

Comment: Got it!  You have subtotals.  Makes sense.  I'll look at it again.